# What does this expression means exactly?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, notation

Let $g:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R^d\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$.

What  does:$$\left | D^\alpha g(h,x) \right |\leq \frac{c}{h}\;,\;\text{for}\;\left | \alpha \right |=2\;\;(c\in\mathbb R^+)$$  mean ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense as is, is $D^\alpha$ in terms of x or h?

Comment: I find it like that in this article http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bramble/psfiles/infsup1018.pdf (Page 3)

Comment: He explains it as any partial derivative of $x_i$ or $y_i$, I think it's necessary to read at least some of this article to make complete sense of the meaning and possible use of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha$ is a multi-index of length $2$. But there can be two options and I can't pinpoint which one it is.

Either $(\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_{d})=\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{1+d}$ and 
$$
D^\alpha g(h,x)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial h}\right)^{\alpha_0}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)^{\alpha_1}
\cdots
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_d}\right)^{\alpha_d}g(h,x)
$$
or $(\alpha_1.\ldots,\alpha_d)=\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^d$ and
$$
D^\alpha g(h,x)=
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)^{\alpha_1}
\cdots
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_d}\right)^{\alpha_d}g(h,x).
$$
In both cases $2=|\alpha|=\sum_{i}\alpha_i$.

Maybe it becomes clear, when he use this property later?

Comment: It is the same problem that I found; I do not know if he considered $h$ as variable and therefore your first notation, else your second notation is true.. anyway, I will see after..Thank you